# How can i set isdigit() command as a variable?

Tags: python, variables, types

I'm new to python but I caught on to the basics pretty quick and decided to start trying to make a program while I'm still learning, since I learn best by actually doing things.

So I'm making a program in python that will add polynomials and I need to see if a character from the parser is numeric im using the `isdigit()` command.

Instead of having to type `isdigit()` all the time in my code such as `n.isdigit()`, I want to assign it to a variable `t = 'isdigit()'` and then type `n.t`. This doesn't work, so is there an alternative to not typing the whole command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can start your code with something like `t = str.isdigit` and then check `t(n)` (you can't make it an attribute of strings because you can't intercept attribute lookup from the outside), this is actually a pretty bad idea. While it's quicker to type, it is significantly harder to read. This will bite you (or anyone else) working the code in a few weeks from now. This is not because abstracting over unnecessary details is bad (it isn't), this snippet simply isn't complicated enough to benefit from an abstraction. Any readable name for this is at least as long as `isidigt`, so you can't actually win any readability.

Comment: thanks I decided to use the T(n) thing, and im writing a key to the code so that it doesnt get confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to create a custom function or lambda to call the `isdigit()` method for you, given an instance:

```
t = lambda n: n.isdigit()

# ...

t(n)  # returns the result of `n.isdigit()`
```

or you could store a reference to the class method:

```
t = str.isdigit

# ...

t(n)  # returns the result of `str.isdigit(n)`
```

as `n` is of type `str`.

The syntax `n.t` *always* will look up `t` as an attribute on `n`, and the local variable `t` is never consulted for that.

Comment: Or `t = str.isdigit`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function:

```
def t(n):
    if n.isdigit():
        return True
    else:
        return False

a = "a5b"
print t(a[1])
```

I don't know if this is what u were looking for.

Comment: Your definition of `t` is about four lines too long.

Comment: Yes, the question was about shorting the call from "isdigit" to "t" so you can save 6 letters, not shorting the definition of the function, and since he said he is a new to python, i think this is a clearer way.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. I believe that the clearest definition of `t` is four lines shorter than your definition. It may not be *immediately* clear to beginners, but that doesn't mean we should discard the opportunity to teach them something along the way.

Comment: So, your alternative could be an improvement, but not immediately clear to beginners, as you said. I think you are right.